# DML operations on Views in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Can an update on a view affects base table also?
For example,

```
CREATE TABLE MyEmployees
(
EmployeeID smallint NOT NULL,
FirstName nvarchar(30)  NOT NULL,
LastName  nvarchar(40) NOT NULL)
```

I have created a view on MyEmployees table.

```
CREATE VIEW View_Mymployees
AS
SELECT * from MyEmployees
```

Now, I am trying to update view,

```
UPDATE View_Mymployees
SET FirstName = 'Adam'
WHERE EmployeeID = 1.
```

Will the changes get reflected in the base table also?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0458/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If the update to the view succeeds then it is the base table(s) that are updated. The view has no data of it's own. See the section "Updatable Views" in the MSDN page for [CREATE VIEW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).